# Rider. EF Code First Migrations

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations, rider

Is there an easy way to scaffold migrations using old EF outside of Visual Studio? I would like to do it via Rider IDE if it possible.

Comment: You can run migrations with [migrate.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj618307(v=vs.113).aspx). Also, specify EF6 vs EF Core.

Answer (score 13):

I don't see these options related to ef core. The plugin makes sense.

(For MacOS, be sure, your dotnet root folder path is `/usr/local/share/dotnet/`. I'm telling this because Rider installs and places it in another folder. Further it gives rise ef to not work properly. You can see your dotnet folder on terminal by writing `which dotnet`)

Installing that plugin,
[image]

Then,

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can also use a jetbrains plugin made for handling migrations

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/17026

Answer (score 2):

For EF Core, you can use https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2017/08/09/running-entity-framework-core-commands-rider/

For EF 6 you may want to check https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2018/04/06/entity-framework-support-rider-2018-1/

Comment: But with `migrate.exe` for `EF 6` how can I make `update-database` or `add-migration`?

Comment: Check https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2018/04/06/entity-framework-support-rider-2018-1/ for EF6

Answer (score 0):

The [Package Manager Console tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/powershell) such as `Add-Migration`, `Scaffold-DbContext` commands are PowerShell-based, and the Package Manager Console ties to several Visual Studio-specific objects making it impossible to host it elsewhere - in your case Rider.

In Rider's terminal or anywhere outside of Visual Studio, you can use [CLI tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet). Equivalents to the highlighted commands would be respectively:

- `Add-Migration` => `dotnet ef migrations add MigrationName`
- `Scaffold-DbContext` => `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold`

You can get more details on JetBrains blog: [Running EF Core commands in Rider](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2017/08/09/running-entity-framework-core-commands-rider/)