# Enabling EF Core functions in Rider

Tags: rider

I installed the EF Core package, and have reloaded everything multiple times. This is a brand new project and I've only just started using Rider, so it's not a legacy project issue as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48086047/rider-ef-code-first-migrations).

The [docs make it look really simple to do](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2018/04/06/entity-framework-support-rider-2018-1/), but then... nothing in the menu. Did it get moved and the docs not updated? I cannot find it if so.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The blog post you mentioned is a bit older - It seems to me that JetBrains' approach has changed.

Try to install [this plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/18147-entity-framework-core-ui) which is mentioned in [this](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2022/01/31/entity-framework-core-inside-rider-ui-way/) newer blog post.

Another option would be to install EF Core v6 instead of v7 because the latter one is still in preview.